# Correctly issuing a POST query via httr for a SPARQL publicly available endpoint

Tags: r, post, httprequest, sparql, httr

I'm trying to source some publicly available data using SPARQL endpoint offered via statistics.gov.scot. The [API page](https://statistics.gov.scot/sparql) recommends using POST.

> **Option 1: POST (recommended)** 
>   Issue a POST to the endpoint, with the query in the body, and an Accept header of sparql-results+json:
>
> ```
> POST http://statistics.gov.scot/sparql HTTP/1.1 Host:
> statistics.gov.scot Accept: application/sparql-results+json
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
> query=SELECT+%2A+WHERE+%7B%3Fs+%3Fp+%3Fo%7D+LIMIT+10
> ```

## Problem

I'm trying to run query that would produce a table with available geographies in the following manner:

```
  response <- httr::POST(
    url = "http://statistics.gov.scot/sparql.csv",
    query = "PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>  
             SELECT  ?hierarchy ?label 
                WHERE {   ?hierarchy  
                           rdfs:subPropertyOf     
                              <http://statistics.gov.scot/def/hierarchy/best-fit>  ;  
                            rdfs:label ?label } ")
```

The results return a code for a wrong response:

```
 httr::status_code(response)
[1] 400
```

### Query

The query works fine when tested against the web based enpoint interface (https://statistics.gov.scot/sparql-beta).

```
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>  
SELECT  ?hierarchy  ?label 
 WHERE {   
  ?hierarchy  
  rdfs:subPropertyOf  <http://statistics.gov.scot/def/hierarchy/best-fit>  ;
  rdfs:label ?label }
```

Comment: There's a `.csv` extension on your httr POST request url that shouldn't be there, I think.

Comment: true! I can think of  that the TO clicked on *"Downloads -> CSV"* in the web interface which usually defaults to a file called `sparql.csv` - so minor typo here with huge impact.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**JSON**

```
response <- httr::POST(
    url = "http://statistics.gov.scot/sparql", accept("application/sparql-results+json"),
    body = list( query = "SELECT * { ?s ?p ?o } LIMIT 10" )
    )
content(response, "text")
```

or (endpoint-specific)

```
response <- httr::POST(
    url = "http://statistics.gov.scot/sparql.json",
    body = list( query = "SELECT * { ?s ?p ?o } LIMIT 10" )
    )
content(response, "text")
```

**CSV**

```
response <- httr::POST(
    url = "http://statistics.gov.scot/sparql", accept("text/csv"),
    body = list( query = "SELECT * { ?s ?p ?o } LIMIT 10" )
    )
content(response, "text")
```

or (endpoint-specific)

```
response <- httr::POST(
    url = "http://statistics.gov.scot/sparql.csv",
    body = list( query = "SELECT * { ?s ?p ?o } LIMIT 10" )
    )
content(response, "text")
```